# QHBoxLayout add widget in a different order

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlayout

writing QHBoxLayout.addWidget() adds the widget to the right. Is there a way for me to add it in in a different position, for example, insert it between the last rightmost and second-rightmost widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert a widget in any position using the [`insertWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#insertWidget) method:

Example:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(w)
    for i in range(8):
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("label-{}".format(i))
        hlay.addWidget(label)
    # insert widget between label-6 and label-7
    hlay.insertWidget(hlay.count() - 1, QtWidgets.QPushButton("Press me"))
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]